# "Via MyApp" tag using Twitter4J in a Java Desktop Application

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Well, the title explains my question. I'm developing an app that will be something like a Twitter client, and I can't find a way to make that when I publish a tweet in my account using the app the tweet shows "via MyApp". I'm using another Twitter account, not the one that I used to create the app (I don't know if that has something to be with all this, but could be so I'm telling you). Does anyone know if this is posible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the field guide, your JSON object (named **obj**) has a field **obj["source"]** with the following meaning:

> Utility used to post the Tweet, as an HTML-formatted string. Tweets from the Twitter website have a source value of web.

This means that "via MyApp" value is the client used to post the tweet. You can find the user that posted this tweet in the field **obj["user"]["screen_name"]**

References:

- https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets
- https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users